# Sendgrid APIdynamic teamplate data access issue

Tags: laravel, dynamic, sendgrid

I am facing some difficulties to get the dynamic content in Sendgrid template. This is my json coming from Laravel project. Able to send email successfully. I am trying to get activation_url from dynamic template data . Tried with different ways as

> dynamic_template_data.activation_url and
>   personalizations[0].dynamic_template_data.activation_url .

But not succeeded.

```
{
  "reply_to":{
     "email":"sai_from@gmail.com",
     "name":"CP"
  },
  "personalizations":[
     {
        "to":[
           {
              "email":"sai_to@gmail.com",
              "name":"sai"
           }
        ],
        "dynamic_template_data":{
           "activation_url": "test",
           "name": "sai"
        }
     }
  ],
  "from":{
     "email":"sai_from@gmail.com",
     "name":"Sai"
  },
  "template_id":"d-233d2e990c2a48f3a886091f7c33412e",
  "subject":"Account Activation"
}
```

Thanks,
Sai Kishor

Comment: How do you access data in template?

Comment: {{activation_url}}